# GitHub git pull fatal error cygwin DLL

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I am trying to perform a git pull command from my github cmd using the GitHub desktop client.

For some reason my git pull no longer works, and it spits out the following errors:

```
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Tangle>git pull
      1 [main] sh (6932) C:\Users\dbale\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba565cb218a521411d0e854079a28c\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0xC77400/0xDD7400.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      1 [main] sh 15144 fork: child -1 - forked process 6932 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: retry: No child processes
      4 [main] sh (16184) C:\Users\dbale\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba565cb218a521411d0e854079a28c\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0xC77400/0xEE7400.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
1067828 [main] sh 15144 fork: child -1 - forked process 16184 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: retry: No child processes
      3 [main] sh (6452) C:\Users\dbale\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba565cb218a521411d0e854079a28c\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0xC77400/0x1107400.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
3137324 [main] sh 15144 fork: child -1 - forked process 6452 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: retry: No child processes
      3 [main] sh (10188) C:\Users\dbale\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba565cb218a521411d0e854079a28c\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0xC77400/0xED7400.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
7211236 [main] sh 15144 fork: child -1 - forked process 10188 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: fork: retry: No child processes
```

My cygwin1.dll is located in: C:\cygwin64\bin\

I use github often and I have never experienced this problem before... Can anyone please help me with this...

Thanks!

Comment: It happened to me when I configured git for Android Studio. I don't know if it's also your scenario. I removed **cygwin1.dll** from my android sdk tools path-to-android-sdk\tools\bin. Then I restarted my PC and run GitHub standalone app. Pull request was performed successfully.

Comment: Looks like a reboot after an upgrade can fix this - so it's not a permanent problem. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082278/1880657

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your cygwin as you can see. in compatible dll version.

Can you try and install the git form git-scm and see if the problem still happens?

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error stack with git for windows on Windows 10, with no cygwin1.dll on PC. The solution was to install 32-bit version. 
Sorry, if doesn't answer you question, but this is the first question Google shows when looking for this error. So might be helpful for others, who will meet the same problem with git 2.10.

Comment: This is what worked for me. If you have 64bit git installed on your machine install 32bit version of cygwin otherwise they will not work together

Comment: I run on W7. Cygwin 64 was OK but after installing the full version of Git I had these errors about the DLL while there was a single DLL.
I have installed the 32 bits version of Cygwin instead and it totally fixed it !

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you have in your PATH binaries conflicting. This is typically when you installed Cygwin and Git for windows. The binaries in common are built with different version of Cygwin, and the problem occurs.

Git for Windows comes with **most** Cygwin utilities, so you can uninstall Cygwin.

If you want to use Cygwin, I recommend you to install pure Git binaries and put them in your PATH.

Comment: deleting cygwin folder, git-bash recovered from the errors

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the problem was Android SDK Tools.
When I uninstalled Android SDK Tools Github Desktop worked again.

Comment: Don't why but I just uninstalled Android SDK tools, restarted my PC and voila! its working fine. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to Windows 10 enabled Force randomization for images (Mandatory ASLR) on by default. I had to go to Exploit protection, and configure exceptions for each of the Cygwin programs that GitHub Desktop uses.

On my PC, the Cygwin programs are currently located in C:\Users\cjshaker\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.1.3\resources\app\git\usr\bin

You can learn more about the problem at:
Desktop barfs with cygheap base mismatch detected
https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3096

Chris Shaker