# How to use gitk with msys2?

Tags: windows, git, msys2

I am using MSYS2 in Windows 10. `git` works fine, however `gitk` gives the error:

```
/usr/bin/gitk: line 3: exec: wish: not found
```

Some googling suggested this may be because TK is not installed, however I tried:

```
pacman -S tk
```

which gave the error:

```
error: target not found: tk
```

How do I get gitk to work in this environment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try running the 64-bit MinGW shell (one of the three environments provided by MSYS2), installing the package `mingw-w64-x86_64-tk`, and then running `gitk`.

Gitk works on my system, and `wish` is provided `/mingw64/bin/wish.exe`.

Comment: I had to add `/mingw64/bin` to `$PATH`, but this seems to work.

Comment: That's odd.  That directory should already be on your PATH if you launch MSYS2 with the "MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell" shortcut in your Start Menu or use mingw64_shell.bat.

Comment: Well, since I didn't... ;) Apparently, I skimmed over the "running the 64-bit MinGW shell" part. Sorry about that.

Comment: To make bash use mingw64, make sure you `set MSYSTEM=MINGW64` before starting bash.exe

Comment: And to make git gui work, add this to your .bashrc: `GIT_GUI_LIB_DIR=/c/msys64/usr/share/git-gui/lib`

Answer (score 0):

I confirm `C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit\cmd\gitk.exe` works just fine.

Make sure you are executing it from a regular CMD session or from `C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit\git-bash.exe`

I would not try and run it from a Cygwin session.

Comment: Wha tis the installation procedure for obtaining that version?  (without wrecking my existing msys2 git installation)

Comment: @M.M Simply uncompress `PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit.7z.exe` and update your %PATH%, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34960864/6309: that links give you a detailed installation process, with links to fetch `PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit.7z.exe`.

Comment: You can solve this problem within the MSYS2 environment without downloading third-party executables; see my answer.

Comment: @DavidGrayson you don't need msys2 framework for working with git on Windows: the git-for-windows project already uses msys2: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309

Comment: I am assuming that OP has the need to use MSYS2 for some other reason, and now tries to run gitk from within it. So using a Git distribution which also already includes MSYS2 seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @poke you really don't want to use msys2 just for using git on Windows.

Comment: I'm trying msys2 as a more lightweight alternative to a full cygwin install

Comment: @M.M You really don't need it. At all. And you don't need Cygwin either.  The `git-bash.exe` packaged with git will open a modern msys2-based bash session.

Comment: @VonC I strongly disagree. I've been using MSYS2 primarily for git for coming on 2 years now, and I'm quite happy. This sort of issue is exactly *why* I prefer MSYS2 directly: I can more easily install companion software I need. The only real downside is the fact that every piece of Windows software that depends on git and its brother assumes `git.exe` is globally installed and on your path, something I continue to refuse to do, but I've gotten along pretty well without depending on any of that.

Comment: @jpmc26 Well... I suppose that with the recent Ubuntu bash on Windows(!) (http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/03/ubuntu-on-windows.html?m=1, https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P488, https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/C906)... the all debate will become moot :) I mean, `sudo apt-get install git` will be possible!

Comment: @VonC I saw that. I'm horrified and expect it to be terrible. Plus I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: @jpmc26 After listening to Steve Gibson on Security Now (https://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm), who is just migrating from Xp(!) to Windows 7 (and  intent to remain on 7 for the next 15 years), I hope you have downloaded Gitbson's small utility "never 10": https://www.grc.com/never10.htm