# Asymptote compiled on Git Bash gives Cygwin Error

Tags: latex, git-bash, git-for-windows, latexmk, asymptote

I recently installed Asymptote 2.78 and GhostScript 9.55 (as the MikTeX installation on Windows screws them both). I also deleted the old MikTeX packages. I wanted to compile a LaTeX file with asymptote code in it. When I compile it, MikTeX again downloads the old Asymptote (which I then delete) and produces a *.asy file. I have the asymptote exe here: `C:\Program Files\Asymptote\asy.exe`. When I run it on my *.asy (on GIT BASH), it produces the follwing error:

```
  0 [main] asy (5248) C:\Program Files\Asymptote\asy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base
  mismatch detected - 0x180349408/0x180346408.
  This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
  Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
  and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
  reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
  installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
  are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
```

Now here's the funny bit: *I have not installed Cygwin on my Windows machine whatsoever.* I even searched my computer using the Everything Search engine. There is no other cygwin1.dll. But there are some other cygwins belonging to Git. When I run the stuff from Windows Command Prompt, it works (even when I do not delete the MikTeX asy)! This is when I do `latexmk -pdf *.tex` on cmd prompt. I do not understand what is going on. Please help!!

Comment: Also yes, I have restarted a zillion times.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if a rebase of the `msys-2.0.dll`, as [I suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34960864/6309), would work.
(Do it in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`)

Make sure to use the [latest Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

The alternative would be to [use WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) and benefit from a full-fledged Linux environment.

Comment: I tried to follow the "more complete process". Maybe a zero is missing in the 7600... and 3000... (because earlier they gave error and after adding a zero they were fine). However, the last command gives this error: `cp: cannot create regular file './msys-2.0.dll': Device or resource busy` (when run from Cmd Prompt (Admin) : idk how to open Git in Admin mode)

Comment: Also I added `C:\Program Files\Git` etc. folders to $PATH so that I have to do windows key + R ==> type git-bash to open a git terminal at ~ (even when I type git-bash in cmd, it opens). My Git version is latest (checked by doing git --version)

Comment: "Device or resource busy": some other process must keep an handle on the file: try just after a reboot.

Comment: I have tried after restarting many times but it is always busy... Can you tell me what to do manually?

Comment: On Windows, you can execute (no installation required) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer, and search for "`msys-2.0.dll`": that will give you the process with an handle on it.